# Mysql format string when like compare

Tags: mysql, ruby

How could i tell mysql to compare my like condition, so that mysql before delete spaces from string and make symbols uppercase...
For example, now my ruby code is such:

```
LineItem.find(:all, :conditions => ["(description like ?) and (order_id in (?))", "%#{params[:art_order_search]}%", orders.map(&:id)])
```

But how can i do, that mysql field description (do not commit any changes to db) when i compare it to like, do something, as ruby gsub do: for example:
now i will have something like this:

```
description in db = ololo from lol oc 90
select * from ooo where description like "OC90"
```

but how can i do, that when i compare, my field is:

```
OLOLOFROMLOL**OC90**
```

Just what function and how to write here: (description like ?)  ???
ruby string analog is:

```
.gsub(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, '').upcase
```

but how to do it for mysql, and by mysql?

*If something is not clear, please don't give me minus, just ask in comments...*

maybe with TRIM and UPPER, but how?

Comment: Assuming that ruby translates the condition to proper sql then what you do is description like '%searchString%' HOWEVER it cannot shift case in any way that I know of.

Comment: @SASS_Shooter but how then compare for example oc90 and OC90, there are equal

Comment: @SASS_Shooter UPPER for example...

Comment: all I have to say is...DOH  So UPPER(description) LIKE '%yourvalue%'

Comment: @SASS_Shooter em, what? what a DOH? And how to delete spaces?