# Mysql compare string without spaces with db-field with spaces

Tags: mysql, ruby, space

I have few fields which i must compare with mysql fields:
For example:

> 0092S40050

but in db i have

> 0 092 S40 050

They are equal, but with spaces, and without them......
But how to do this with mysql query on ruby?

My question is a little bit same as:
[Mysql format string when like compare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14840754/mysql-format-string-when-like-compare)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you can do something like this in MySql

```sql
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE REPLACE(mycolumn, ' ', '') = '0092S40050'
```

or

```sql
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE REPLACE(mycolumn, ' ', '') LIKE '____S50%'
```

Here is [sqlfidlle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4d460/4)